# Why is my printing of a char not working?

Tags: c, char, printf

This is blowing my mind. I literally have no idea what this is about. I have the following code:

```
char cSexMF = 'M';

printf("%c \n", &cSexMF);
```

It should output M however every time I run the code it comes out with a different number or letter or symbol or whatever it fancies really. I thought this was a straightforward command but apparently I can't even do them anymore.

Can anyone offer some insight into why this is happening?

Comment: Why & ? Do you want the character or its memory address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are passing the wrong parameter.

The `"%c"` specifier expects a `char` and you are passing the address of your variable which has type `char *`.

To make it work, just remove the `&` address of operator

```
printf("%c\n", cSexMF);
```

You might be confused because if it was `scanf()` the `&` would be required, the reason is that `scanf()` needs to modify the content of the variable, for which you pass it's address and it modifies it through a pointer. The `printf()` function, needs the value, not the address.

And also, enable compiler warnings. As a programmer learning the c language, it will save you a lot of problems, even experimented programmers use warnings to prevent silly typos.

Comment: oh my god I just realised what an idiot I am. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a pointer. Don't do this.

```
char cSexMF = 'M';
printf("%c \n", cSexMF);
```

When you add `&` in front of a variable name, it results in address extraction. Here you've tried to pass a *pointer to char* to a call that expects *char*.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the unary `&` before a variable, it returns the address of that variable. So, you are trying to print the address of `cSexMF` and not the value held by it.

When using `printf()` , you don't need to add the `&` , just

```
printf("%c \n", cSexMF);
```

is enough ( unless you actually want to output the address, but then you need to use the `%p` type specifier ) .

Normally, when you use `scanf()` , you add the `&` before the variable ( because you store the value at that address ) , but you don't need to do so when using `printf()`